# embedded jetty in spring, hibernate and jersey apis using war

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey, jetty

Can anybody help me to sort out my issues related embedded jetty with spring ioc, jersey and hibernation combination. 
Here is my main method

I've a module called repose-config-apis which packaged as **war** inside this module i've various resources under a package end up with .reouces
in a separate package known as org.companyname.jettyintegration
there is a main class listed below

```
package org.openrepose.jetty.integration;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class JettyIntegration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        // Create the server
        Server server = new Server(8080);


        // Create a WebApp
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/repose-config-apis/webapi/*");
        webapp.setWar("src/main/webapp");
        server.setHandler(webapp);

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }

}
```

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>org.openrepose.apis.spring.config.SpringJerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.openrepose.apis.exceptions.mappers</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

URL mapping is /webapi/*
hence when i was deploying this war in tomcat i was able to access apis using below format 
http://localhost:8080/repose-config-apis/webapi/myapi

Now after jetty embedded, when i'm trying excute main method (using eclipse run as java app) i'm getting below error (because of spring)

```
[WARN ] 2015-08-26 14:13:58.349 [main] WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@45d84a20{/repose-config-apis/webapi,file:///home/guptanitin/Office/testingjettey/api_mgmt_gateway/repose-aggregator/repose-config-apis/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{src/main/webapp}
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798) ~[jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:771) ~[jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1368) ~[jetty-webapp-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1335) ~[jetty-webapp-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:735) ~[jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259) ~[jetty-servlet-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:511) [jetty-webapp-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405) [jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106) [jetty-util-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372) [jetty-server-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.2.v20150730.jar:9.3.2.v20150730]
    at org.openrepose.jetty.integration.JettyIntegration.main(JettyIntegration.java:105) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getMethodIfAvailable(ClassUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<clinit>(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 30 more
```

My pom file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
        <artifactId>profile-support</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>repose-config-apis</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>repose-config-apis</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <logback.version>1.1.2</logback.version>
        <org.springframework.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jersey+spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- For JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version> </dependency> -->






        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- external dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-base</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-apis-payload</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-catalog</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP Client dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrepose</groupId>
            <artifactId>repose-config-exceptions</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>repose-config-apis</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.2.v20150730</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <!-- make jetty listen on 127.0.0.1 for better security -->
                        <!--host>127.0.0.1</host -->
                    </httpConnector>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <!-- defaultsDescriptor>src/test/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor -->
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <server>QnA Tomcat Server</server>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i'm using spring 4.1.5 ,  hibernate 4 and jersey 2.

Please help to sort this out

Answer (score 0):

According to the given stack trace, I guess you're missing some dependencies which are already provided in Tomcat's lib folder. That explains why it works running the app on Tomcat, but fails when being deployed on embedded Jetty. Check the dependencies in your pom.xml against Tomcat's inherent JARs and add what's missing.

Edit: Since you're missing javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType, hibernate-jpa may be a good starting point.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Hello @PatrickOutOfBounds thank you for ur suggestion,
Yesterday i tried few more tricks and luckly i solved the above issue. 
I've changed my jettyintegration by introducing 


 ' final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  context.setConfigLocation("org.openrepose.apis");
  context.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("dev");

webAppContext.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
'